# How to combine particular results in a larger result set in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've set up a 'Top 20' report within our ticketing system to show the clients which log the most tickets.
Most clients consist of a single 'account' within the system but a new client consists of 17 individual 'accounts' for the one actual client.

When running the Top 20 report, I now need to combine the 17 results together to be 1 'main' account total for this client within the rest of the results. The 17 individual 'accounts' never make it into the Top 20 while the combined sum would but unsure how to modify my query to do this just for the one particular client.

Original:

```
SELECT TOP 20    
    wh_account.account_name AS 'Client',    
    COUNT(wh_task.task_number) AS 'Total'    
FROM wh_account    
LEFT JOIN wh_task 
  ON wh_task.account_id = wh_account.account_id    
WHERE wh_task.create_time BETWEEN @StartofLastMonth AND @EndofLastMonth
GROUP BY wh_account.account_name
ORDER BY COUNT(wh_task.task_number) DESC
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join result. (Now it executes as regular inner join.)

Comment: You should probably either add  `clients` and `client_accounts`, or else a `client` column to the `wh_account` table to handle this and future cases of multi-account clients, instead of special-caseing it in the code.

Comment: Thanks RBarryYoung. Unfortunately the db is provided by a 3rd party and we don't have access to add further columns, tables etc. We're limited to read only access from their setup. Not ideal I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add up the values from these 17 accounts in 1.  The way to do that is using window functions.  You can even do this just in the `ORDER BY` clause if you like:

```
SELECT TOP 20 a.account_name AS Client,    
       COUNT(t.task_number) AS Total   
FROM wh_account a LEFT JOIN
     wh_task t
     ON t.account_id = a.account_id    
WHERE t.create_time BETWEEN @StartofLastMonth AND @EndofLastMonth
GROUP BY a.account_name
ORDER BY SUM(COUNT(t.task_number)) OVER
             (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN a.account_name NOT IN (<list of 17 goes here>)
                                 THEN a.account_name
                            END)
             );
```

This version leaves the 17 on their own rows, but will include them in the top 20, if appropriate.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you might want to see all 17 on a single row rather than on 17 rows.  If so, use `CASE` for the aggregation:

```
SELECT TOP 20
       (CASE WHEN a.account_name IN (<list of 17 here>)
               THEN 'Main' ELSE a.account_name
        END) AS Client,    
       COUNT(t.task_number) AS Total   
FROM wh_account a LEFT JOIN
     wh_task t
     ON t.account_id = a.account_id    
WHERE t.create_time BETWEEN @StartofLastMonth AND @EndofLastMonth
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN a.account_name IN (<list of 17 here>)
               THEN 'Main' ELSE a.account_name
          END)
```

Comment: You're a legend Gordon Linoff!. The second option is all I needed. I wasn't aware you could add the same CASE statement to a GROUP BY. Modified my query and tested and works perfectly.